# Hand tracking support for Oculus Quest 2 in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculusquest

I am able to build and run my app for Oculus Quest 2 using Unity 2020.2. However, I'm trying to get the hand interaction to work. In the HandInteractionTrainScene from the Oculus Integration package, I tell me I need to enable hand tracking.

I've searched around a bit and this should be solved by setting the "Hand Tracking Support" in OVRCameraRig to "Hands Only". Problem is that the field is disabled and I can't figure out why. I've been struggling with this for a while now.

[image: OVRCameraRig with OVR Manager script]

Does anyone have any suggestion on what the root cause might be?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the quest features section you should switch the build platform to Android  (File->Build Settings->Android->switch platform).

Answer (score 0):

My Unity editor version: 2021.3.5f1

**To enable hand tracking using Oculus integration**

---

1. Go to **Window** > **Package Manager** > *Packages: In Project*

> make sure **Oculus XR Plugin** is imported and up to date.

[view example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZjYo.png)

---

2. Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **XR Plug-in Management** > *Windows, Mac, Linux settings* (monitor icon)

> tick the following:
>
> - *Initialize XR on Startup*
> - *Oculus*

[view example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yc4I.png)

---

3. Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **XR Plug-in Management** > *Android settings* (android icon)

> tick the following:
>
> - *Initialize XR on Startup*
> - *Oculus*

[see example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2R1G.png)

---

4. Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Player** > *Android settings* (android icon) > **Other Settings**

> In the **Configuration** section do:
>
> - Scripting Backend: *IL2CPP*
> - Untick *ARMv7*
> - Tick *ARM64*
> - Active Input Handling: *Both*

[see example 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwpjL.png)

---

5. In the **Project** section search for *OVRCameraRig* prefab

> - Drag it to the **Hierarchy** section

[see example 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6XV9.png)

---

6. In the **Project** section search for *OVRHandPrefab* prefab

> In the *Hierarchy* section do:
>
> - expand *OVRCameraRig*
> - expand *LeftHandAnchor*
> - expand *RightHandAnchor*
> - drag the **OVRHandPrefab** prefab from the *Project* section and drop it as a child for *LeftHandAnchor* and *RightHandAnchor*

[see example 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkeQO.png)

---

7. Click on **OVRHandPrefab** prefab under *LeftHandAnchor* and ensure:

> In the *Inspector* section:
>
> - Hand Type: *Hand Left*
> - Skeleton Type: *Hand Left*
> - Mesh Type: *Hand Left*

[see example 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdNdX.png)

---

8. Click on **OVRHandPrefab** prefab under *RightHandAnchor* and ensure:

> In the *Inspector* section:
>
> - Hand Type: *Hand Right*
> - Skeleton Type: *Hand Right*
> - Mesh Type: *Hand Right*

[see example 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APXFf.png)

---

9. Click on **OVRCameraRig** and select:

> In the *Inspector* section:
>
> - Hand Tracking Support: *Hands Only*

---

10. To adjust the tracking origin click on **OVRCameraRig** and choose from:

> In the *Inspector* section:
>
> - Tracking Origin Type: *Eye Level*, *Floor Level*, *Stage*

---

11. Go to **File** > **Build Settings**

> - Add the appropriate scene in the *Scenes In Build*
> - Platform: *Android*
> - In *Android* section > Run Device: [your Oculus]
> - Click on **Build And Run**

---

**Conclusion**

I assume you have your Oculus device plugged in to your computer and it is in *Developer mode* and you cannot test the hand tracking in play mode in Unity.